# Inno Setup ask user for special locations

Tags: path, installation, inno-setup

I'm new with Inno setup. I want the user to select during installation a different path to install e.g. the database (normaly it will be installed in ProgramData..). So I want to get the installation path dialog a second time for the database or any other files.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to create custom page and show it before the installation (progress page) starts.

> Prototype: function CreateCustomPage(const AfterID: Integer; const
>   ACaption, ADescription: String): TWizardPage;
>
> Description: Creates a custom wizard page. The page is empty by
>   default; you have to create your own controls afterward and place them
>   on the page (by setting their Parent properties to the Surface
>   property of the TWizardPage instance returned by this function).
>
> Example: See CodeClasses.iss for an example.

So create custom page, place some controls on it (file picker of directory picker) and show when needed.

Comment: wow, this is the easiest way?!
I try to understand the example.

Comment: No, easier (and somehow official) is creating an input dir. wizard page by using [`CreateInputDirPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage) function.

Comment: I underestimated the power and complexity of inno setup; my respect for that and the best it is free.
I solved the problem